# Designing two DB tables with same id? Good practices?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I have to take an online course on DB design once again since I got a really lazy teacher that I thought had taught us everything and I continue to find out he didn't.

I'm designing a small DB in which two particular tables brought up this question.

I have a table called "Athlete" which stores Athlete info and a second table called "EntryInfo" which stores a guy's objectives, if he was a referral by another athlete.

There is no way an athlete could have more than one of this entry infos, so I thought idAthlete would apply to both "Athlete" and "EntryInfo" but I don´t know if this is correct or not. Now I have these questions:

1) In trying to keep "**Athlete**" table as clean as possible I didn't include this "**EntryInfo**" in the "**Athlete**" table from the beginning but it COULD be in the same table. Is this the best way to handle it? Regarding good practices in DB design should they be in 1 or 2 tables?

2) If it´s better to keep it in two separate tables, can I have *idAthlete* as PK in **Athlete** table (identity, incremental) and have it also as a PK in Entry Info only as a FK? or would it be a better practice to have a PK identity incremental *idEntryInfo* on **EntryInfo** table with a FK idAthlete?

I know this is such a basic question and I know I should take a course on DB design and normalisation (and I will do).

Comment: I would suggest keeping that information in a second table. But go with your second idea there. Meaning you want idAthlete to be a foreign key to the Athlete table. That way when the project expands and you need to accommodate multiple EntryInfo rows per athlete your design supports this with zero modification.

Comment: You speak about them like they're distinct entities, which might be a good argument for keeping them separate. On the flip side of that though, if, as you say, you KNOW there's a 1:1 mapping between the two, keeping two tables with identical primary keys just seems like you're adding more work for yourself.

Comment: Thanks to you both.  Xedni that´s my main doubt. This Entry Info came from a Form the trainer handled to its clients, the info on the form is useful to the guy at the beginning and will never change once a record is added. 

I think I could go either way but don´t know what would be best practice regarding standards.

Answer (score 0):

When you have two tables with the same key it's called *vertical partitioning* and it's a valid design for various reasons.

However I don't see any reasons in your explanation. I only see your statement *keep "Athlete" table as clean as possible*, which has a pretty general meaning. If you're going to put different groups of fields into different tables you can categorise that any number of ways

If you had a zillion records and you had performance issues it might be worth considering.

It will be simpler for you if you keep it in one table, then you don't have to fiddle about synchronising keys between the tables